# Quarkus splash screen disable or change

Tags: quarkus

How can I disable or customize quarkus based cli application splash screen?
I can't find proper information in documentation or tutorials.

Comment: Set the [`quarkus.banner.enabled`](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-core_quarkus.banner.enabled) configuration property to false.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ChinHuang mind adding that as answer so future readers can easily see it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the Quarkus banner, set the [`quarkus.banner.enabled`](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-core_quarkus.banner.enabled) configuration property to false.

Answer (score 2):

Using `quarkus.banner.enabled` can be used to disable the banner - as Chin Huang already mentioned. To customize/replace it you can use `quarkus.banner.path`.

Source: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started#banner